# Solutions of the differential equation $f'=(f^{-1})^{[n]}$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, functional-equations

**For clarity, we use the notations $f^{[n]}=f\circ  \dots\circ f$ for nesting and $f^{(n)}=\frac d{dx}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\dots\right)f$ for differentiation.**

After reading these two posts ([here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34052/function-satisfying-f-1-f) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111066/are-there-any-techniques-for-solving-a-differential-equation-of-the-form-f-x)) on MO, I couldn't help but wonder what would happen if we were to iterate $f^{-1}$ on that DE. I first started by trying to merge arguments from both pages to see if it could work, to no avail: to my understanding, one has to simply further or adapt the techniques presented on the first page, as the presence of the inverse makes the problem fundamentally different (and more difficult). I haven't managed to go further than the trivial analysis:

Pick an ansatz of the form $ax^b$ and substitute. Equate the powers and the coefficients:

$\begin{cases}
b-1=\frac{1}{b^n} \iff b^{n+1}-b^{n}-1=0 \\
a=b^{\frac{-b^2}{b^2+b+1}}
\end{cases}$

Fortunately, the polynomial in $b$ always has a positive root so there is always this solution. What other solutions are there and how to find them?
I have willingly not specified the domain for $x$, pick whatever suits your answers, or even better, discuss the several possibilities.

One can push this one step forward and explore DEs of the form:
$$F(x,f',...,f^{(n)},f^{-1},(f^{-1})^{[2]},...,(f^{-1})^{[n]})=0$$
as presented similarly by this [article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3423/2958018c57a67fad39ffdb194d6549136ff9.pdf).

Any and all ideas are appreciated!